# Rotate Object in Sketch Up Ruby Script

Tags: ruby, sketchup

I'm trying to create a several cylinders with a loop, rotating each one slightly in 3 dimensions each time, a random amount.

Here's what I have so far:

```
until i == 200
        x += rand(10)
        y += rand(10)
        z += rand(10)
        xyz = rand(2)
        circle = entities.add_circle([x,y,z], axis[xyz], r, n)
        base = entities.add_face(circle)
        base.pushpull -h
        base.transform_entities(Geom::Transformation.rotation([0,0,0],[1,0,0],rand(360)),base)
        i += 1
        #sleep 0.2
    end
```

The transform_entities throws this error:

```
Error: #<NoMethodError: undefined method `transform_entities' for <Sketchup::Face:0x18836040>>
```

Any ideas how I can make this work? I've dug through the API docs but can't figure out a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Sidenote - looks like you're trying to animate. In which case have a look at the `Animation` class: http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/docs/ourdoc/animation

Comment: @thomthom kind of - trying to recursively generative elements. a very crude generative architecture algorithm. thanks for the pointer though, will check that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was incorrectly applying the transform to base rather than entities.

Should be:

```
entities.transform_entities(Geom::Transformation.rotation([0,0,0],[1,0,0],rand(360)),base)
```